# How do I detect text that's being highlighted in my windows phone 7 app?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm wonder if there's a way to detect whether or not text is being highlighted in a windows phone 7 silverlight application? If so how would I listen for this event?

To clarify, if I have a text box filled with "Lorem ipsum sit amet", and the user attempts to highlight "ipsum sit", how can I detect this? Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subscribe to the [SelectionChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectionchanged%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).

If the text and the selection is changed in a TextBox, the TextChanged event is raised before the SelectionChanged event

The [SelectionStart Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectionstart%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) and the [SelectionLength Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectionlength%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) may also be helpful depending on your needs.